# Erro ao rodar Dropdownlist em ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

**Estou tendo o seguinte erro na hora de rodar:**

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Não existe item ViewData do tipo 'IEnumerable' que possui a chave 'SexoID'.'

Segue código abaixo:

**Model:**

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo sexo é obrigatório!")]
    public int SexoID { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult DropDown()
    {
        var model = new CadastroModel();

        ViewBag.Sexo = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Selecione", Value="", Selected = true},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Masculino", Value="1"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Feminino", Value="2"},

        };

        return View(CadastrarUsuario);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DropDown(CadastroModel CadastrarUsuario)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return View(CadastrarUsuario);
        }



        ViewBag.Sexo = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Selecione", Value="", Selected = true},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Masculino", Value="1"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Feminino", Value="2"},

        };

        return View(CadastrarUsuario);
    }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <div class="editor-label col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SexoID)

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.SexoID, ViewBag.Sexo as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Selecione")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.SexoID)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro ocorre porque na sua lista de sexos(`new SelectListItem { Text = "Masculino", Value="1"}`) não tem o campo **SexoId**, porém no seu `DropDownList(@Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.SexoID...))` você indica que terá a propriedade com esse nome.

No momento penso em duas maneiras de resolver esse problema

**1ª:**

Invés de usar o `DropDownListFor` usar o `DropDownList`, assim não irá "forçar" que tenha uma propriedade com esse nome na lista

```
@Html.DropDownList("SexoId", ViewBag.Sexo as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Selecione")
```

**2ª:**

Criar uma classe(que contem a propriedade **SexoId**), uma lista dessa classe e montar o `DropDownList`

```
public class Sexo
{
    public int SexoId { get; set; }
    public string Texto { get; set; }
}

List<Sexo> sexos = new List<Sexo>{
    new Sexo{ SexoId=1, Texto = "Masculino" },
    new Sexo{ SexoId=2, Texto = "Feminino" }
};

ViewBag.Sexo = new SelectList(sexos, "SexoId", "Texto");

@Html.DropDownListFor(e=> e.SexoId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Sexo, "Selecione")
```